# prev / nex post links does not work if polylang custom post traslations is on

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, polylang

As I wrote in the title, custom posts previous, and next_post_links are working fine, but if I activate polylang-s custom post traslations, they do not work anymore
This is the code:

```
<div class = "page-content">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>   
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?> 
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( is_single() ) { ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class = "prev-next-links">
    <div class = "previous"><?php previous_post_link(); ?></div>
    <div class = "next"><?php next_post_link(); ?></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fond the problem, the post were not assigned to any language.